# My nagios instance is running notify-service-by-email 4 times for every iteration

Tags: bash, nagios

I created my own bash script for notify-service-by-email. Problem is that every time alert is triggered, nagios runs this script exactly 4 times instead of once. 
I'm running nagios 3.5.1-1 on Red Hat 6.4

**commands.cfg**

```
define command{
command_name    notify-service-by-email
command_line    /home/nagios/scripts/notify_by_email/notify.bash "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$" "$SERVICEDESC$" "$HOSTNAME$" "$SERVICESTATE$" "$LONGDATETIME$" "$SERVICEOUTPUT$" "$CONTACTEMAIL$"
}
```

When I ran script manually from command line, it ran once - so it's not loop in the script.

I tried to search for suspicious entry in the main config file, but with no success.

**nagios.cfg**

```
log_file=/var/log/nagios/nagios.log
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/commands_manual.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/contacts.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/timeperiods.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/templates.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/services_prod.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/services_uat.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/objects/services_actimize.cfg
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios/servers
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios/objects/SC4
object_cache_file=/var/log/nagios/objects.cache
precached_object_file=/var/log/nagios/objects.precache
resource_file=/etc/nagios/private/resource.cfg
status_file=/var/log/nagios/status.dat
status_update_interval=10
nagios_user=nagios
nagios_group=nagios
check_external_commands=1
command_check_interval=-1
command_file=/var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd
external_command_buffer_slots=4096
lock_file=/var/run/nagios.pid
temp_file=/var/log/nagios/nagios.tmp
temp_path=/tmp
event_broker_options=-1
log_rotation_method=d
log_archive_path=/var/log/nagios/archives
use_syslog=1
log_notifications=1
log_service_retries=1
log_host_retries=1
log_event_handlers=1
log_initial_states=0
log_external_commands=1
log_passive_checks=1
service_inter_check_delay_method=s
max_service_check_spread=30
service_interleave_factor=s
host_inter_check_delay_method=s
max_host_check_spread=30
max_concurrent_checks=0
check_result_reaper_frequency=10
max_check_result_reaper_time=30
check_result_path=/var/log/nagios/spool/checkresults
max_check_result_file_age=3600
cached_host_check_horizon=15
cached_service_check_horizon=15
enable_predictive_host_dependency_checks=1
enable_predictive_service_dependency_checks=1
soft_state_dependencies=0
auto_reschedule_checks=0
auto_rescheduling_interval=30
auto_rescheduling_window=180
sleep_time=0.25
service_check_timeout=60
host_check_timeout=30
event_handler_timeout=30
notification_timeout=30
ocsp_timeout=5
perfdata_timeout=5
retain_state_information=1
state_retention_file=/var/log/nagios/retention.dat
retention_update_interval=60
use_retained_program_state=1
use_retained_scheduling_info=1
retained_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_service_attribute_mask=0
retained_process_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_process_service_attribute_mask=0
retained_contact_host_attribute_mask=0
retained_contact_service_attribute_mask=0
interval_length=60
check_for_updates=1
bare_update_check=0
use_aggressive_host_checking=0
execute_service_checks=1
accept_passive_service_checks=1
execute_host_checks=1
accept_passive_host_checks=1
enable_notifications=1
enable_event_handlers=1
process_performance_data=1
host_perfdata_file=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/host-perfdata
service_perfdata_file=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/service-perfdata
host_perfdata_file_template=DATATYPE::HOSTPERFDATA\tTIMET::$TIMET$\tHOSTNAME::$HOSTNAME$\tHOSTPERFDATA::$HOSTPERFDATA$\tHOSTCHECKCOMMAND::$HOSTCHECKCOMMAND$\tHOSTSTATE::$HOSTSTATE$\tHOSTSTATETYPE::$HOSTSTATETYPE$\tHOSTOUTPUT::$HOSTOUTPUT$
service_perfdata_file_template=HOSTNAME:$HOSTNAME$:\tTIME:$DATE$ $TIME$:\tSERVICEDESC:$SERVICEDESC$:\tSERVICEPERFDATA:$SERVICEPERFDATA$:\tSERVICEOUTPUT:$SERVICEOUTPUT$:
host_perfdata_file_mode=a
service_perfdata_file_mode=a
host_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
service_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
host_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-host-perfdata-file
service_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-service-perfdata-file
obsess_over_services=0
obsess_over_hosts=0
translate_passive_host_checks=0
passive_host_checks_are_soft=0
check_for_orphaned_services=1
check_for_orphaned_hosts=1
check_service_freshness=1
service_freshness_check_interval=60
service_check_timeout_state=c
check_host_freshness=0
host_freshness_check_interval=60
additional_freshness_latency=15
enable_flap_detection=1
low_service_flap_threshold=5.0
high_service_flap_threshold=20.0
low_host_flap_threshold=5.0
high_host_flap_threshold=20.0
date_format=us
p1_file=/usr/sbin/p1.pl
enable_embedded_perl=1
use_embedded_perl_implicitly=1
illegal_object_name_chars=`~!$%^&*|'"<>?,()=
illegal_macro_output_chars=`~$&|'"<>
use_regexp_matching=0
use_true_regexp_matching=0
admin_email=super@secret
admin_pager=super@secret
daemon_dumps_core=0
use_large_installation_tweaks=1
enable_environment_macros=1
debug_level=0
debug_verbosity=1
debug_file=/var/log/nagios/nagios.debug
max_debug_file_size=1000000
```

Have you encountered similar issue? What else should I check?

Comment: Does your nagios log file show the execution of the script 4 times?

Comment: Is possible that your bash script for sending email is that problem.

Comment: Guys, thank you for pointing me to right direction

Answer (score 0):

Nagios executes command notify-service-by-email for every single defined contact. In my case I have 4 contacts (e-mails) in the contact group. After I defined singe e-mail address, my problem was resolved.